# dataLayer proper configuration in GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-firebase, google-datalayer

**How should the event trigger be called, based in the example given bellow for generating the dataLayer variable?**

**Right now my Custome Event name is 'purchase', Should I tell the developers just to generate the dataLayer as in the code example in the last part or something must be changed according to my GTM configuration?**

As far as I can understand the backend developer shoud be the responsible for the correct implementation of the dataLayer variable (that is a Javascript Array). But how he/she calls the elements in the dataLayer should match with the Event Name we use in our Custom Event Trigger.

This question arise because a couple of days ago our Ecommerce tracking implementation stop registering transactions, revenue et. al. I did not make the implemention my self, but somehow I'm in charge of fixing it.

The date our GA profile stops recording transaction was 2th of August, at 4 am. That's date there was a implemention in our production server.

**Our Thank you page:**

I was checking the code for our thank you page, I'm noticing dataLayer variable is NOT being populated with the transaction and item(s) information.

[image]

**How it should look like: what I've found in OptimizeSmart blog**

[image]

**GTM UA- Purchase Order TAG & Custom Event Trigger**:

[image]

**Custom Event Trigger**:

[image]

**How to generate the dataLayer with PHP**:

I've found in another answer how the dataLayer can be dynamically populated:

```
<script>
      dataLayer.push({
          'ecommerce': {
            'currencyCode': '<?php echo $order->get_order_currency(); ?>',
            'purchase': {
              'actionField':{
                'id': '<?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>',
                'affiliation': 'WooCommerce',
                'revenue': <?php echo number_format($order->get_subtotal(), 2, ".", ""); ?>,
                'tax': <?php echo number_format($order->get_total_tax(), 2, ".", ""); ?>,
                'shipping': <?php echo number_format($order->calculate_shipping(), 2, ".", ""); ?>,
                <?php if($order->get_used_coupons()): ?>
                    'coupon': '<?php echo implode("-", $order->get_used_coupons()); ?>'
                <?php endif; ?>
              },
              'products': [
                  <?php
                    foreach($order->get_items() as $key => $item):
                      $product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );
                      $variant_name = ($item['variation_id']) ? wc_get_product($item['variation_id']) : '';
                  ?>
                      {
                        'name': '<?php echo $item['name']; ?>',
                        'id': '<?php echo $item['product_id']; ?>',
                        'price': '<?php echo number_format($order->get_line_subtotal($item), 2, ".", ""); ?>',
                        'brand': '',
                        'category': '<?php echo strip_tags($product->get_categories(', ', '', '')); ?>',
                        'variant': '<?php echo ($variant_name) ? implode("-", $variant_name->get_variation_attributes()) : ''; ?>',
                        'quantity': <?php echo $item['qty']; ?>
                      },
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                ]
            }
          }
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datalayer push in the PHP code is missing the event variable, which is set in 'EV - Order Purchase' trigger. This is the reason, why your transaction is not being recorded, as  'UA - Order Purchase' tag is never run by its trigger.

You should use:

```
<script>
  dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'purchase', // same event name as in your trigger 
    'ecommerce': {
      // ecommerce data comes here
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I suspected something like this was missing.